# Pie canvas animation show full circle on one frame

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have pie chart like grow/shrink animation, but in the middle of it, there is showing up fill circle on one frame, how can I get rid of it?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var increase = Math.PI * 2 / 100;
var max = Math.PI * 2;
var angle = 0;
var start = false;  
setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#F00A0A';
  ctx.beginPath();
  if (start) {
    ctx.arc(16, 16, 12, angle, 0);
  } else {
    ctx.arc(16, 16, 12, 0, angle);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(16, 16);
  ctx.fill();
  angle += increase;
  if (angle >= max) {
    angle = 0;
    start = !start;
  }
}, 20);
```

```html
<canvas width="32" height="32"/>
```

I've tried this:

```
  if (angle !== 0) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    if (start) {
      ctx.arc(16, 16, 12, angle, 0);
    } else {
      ctx.arc(16, 16, 12, 0, angle);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(16, 16);
    ctx.fill();
  }
```

but this don't work, when arc change side it show full circle for one frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just offset your angle ever so slightly.

That way circle isn't "complete" when you change drawing mode:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
var canvasSize = canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#F00A0A';
var increase = Math.PI * 2 / 100;
var max = Math.PI * 2;
var angle = 0.0000001;
var start = false;
function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvasSize / 2, canvasSize / 2, canvasSize / 3, angle, 0, start);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasSize / 2, canvasSize / 2);
    ctx.fill();
    angle += increase;
    if (angle >= max) {
        angle = angle % max;
        start = !start;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```